How to evaluate conditionals not deterministic (random order) in Racket/Scheme?
How do I evaluate this code un-deterministically?
(cond (correct-1? do-thing-1)
      (correct-2? do-thing-2)
      (correct-3? do-thing-3))

For example, if correct-1? and correct-3? are true, then I want sometimes to execute do-thing-1 and sometimes do-thing-3. In other words: the order of the conditional declaration does not matter and is decided randomly.

Write your own "random conditional" as a macro. Start reading here.

Such a macro cannot have an else clause for obvious reasons -
(define-syntax rand-cond
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((rand-cond (test expr ...) clause ...)
     (shuffle-eval '((test expr ...) clause ...)))))

We can write shuffle-eval to iterate over each clause and immediately exit when a test clause evaluates to true -
(define (shuffle-eval clauses)
  (call/cc
   (lambda (exit)
     (for-each 
      (lambda (clause)
        (let ((test (car clause))
              (exprs (cdr clause))) 
          (when (eval test) ;; eval test
            (exit (eval `(begin ,@exprs)))))) ;; eval exprs
      (shuffle clauses))     
     #f))) ;; else false

Let's try it out -
(rand-cond
 ((> 5 10) (display "5 is greater than 10"))
 ((< 5 10) (display "5 is less than 10"))
 ((= 5 5) (display "5 is equal to 5")))

Sometimes displays "equal", sometimes displays "less". Never displays "greater".

To run in Racket, eval requires a namespace. You can pass a namespace as a second argument or you can use parameterize to set the current-namespace context -
(define-syntax rand-cond
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((rand-cond (test expr ...) clause ...)
     (parameterize ((current-namespace (make-base-namespace)))
       (shuffle-eval '((test expr ...) clause ...))))))


I don't think it's obvious at all that it can't have an else. :) Just needs a smarter macro. (You also don't need eval if you wrap things up in lambdas)

(Annoyingly, shuffle is not a commonly available function in most of the Schemes I looked at. Should add it to my list of "I really should explore contributing a SRFI for that" items.)

haha  i wrote the post so quickly, i see how that sounds now. i'm only referring to my macro's simple (crude) design!

Here's a Racket version (Using syntax-parse macros) that supports an else case, and => notation.
#lang racket/base

(provide random-cond else =>)
(require (for-syntax racket/base syntax/parse) racket/list)

(begin-for-syntax
  (define-syntax-class cond-clause
    #:literals (=>)
    (pattern (test:expr)
      #:attr then-proc #'values
      #:fail-when (and (identifier? #'test) (free-identifier=? #'test #'else)) "else must be last clause")
    (pattern (test:expr => then-proc:expr)
      #:fail-when (and (identifier? #'test) (free-identifier=? #'test #'else)) "else must be last clause")
    (pattern (test:expr body:expr ...+)
      #:attr then-proc #'(lambda (arg) body ...)
      #:fail-when (and (identifier? #'test) (free-identifier=? #'test #'else)) "else must be last clause")))

(define-syntax (random-cond stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    #:literals (else)
    [(_ clause:cond-clause ... (~optional (else else-body:expr ...+) #:defaults ([(else-body 1) (list #'(void))])))
     #`(let loop ([clauses (shuffle (list #,@(map (lambda (t c) #`(cons (lambda () #,t) #,c))
                                                  (syntax-e #'(clause.test ...))
                                                  (syntax-e #'(clause.then-proc ...)))))])
         (if (null? clauses)
             (let () else-body ...)
             (let ([result ((caar clauses))])
               (if result
                   ((cdar clauses) result)
                   (loop (cdr clauses))))))]))


so happy you took the time to share this, i am learning so much from you ^^

Given a function shuffle which randomly permutes a list then a simple version of cond which does this is as follows:
(define-syntax cond/random
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (test form ...) ...)
     (first-good (shuffle (list (cons (lambda () test) (lambda () form ...)) ...))))))

(define (first-good l)
  (cond ((null? l)
         #f)
        (((car (car l)))
         ((cdr (car l))))
        (else
          (first-good (cdr l)))))

This has no special else case and doesn't understand the alternate Scheme cond syntax.  Neither of those things matter.
R7RS seems not to specify random number generation at all, and the Scheme I have access to right now (LispPad) has a buggy random: here is a version of shuffle which works for it.
(define (shuffle l)
  ;; LispPad's random is buggy.  This will fail for very long lists
  (if (or (null? l) (null? (cdr l)))
      l
      (let* ((v (list->vector l))
             (n (vector-length v)))
        (let sloop ((i (- n 1))
                    (r (fxrandom n)))
          (cond ((zero? i)
                 (vector->list v))
                ((= r i)
                 (sloop (- i 1) (fxrandom i)))
                (else
                 (let ((e (vector-ref v r)))
                   (vector-set! v r (vector-ref v i))
                   (vector-set! v i e))
                  (sloop (- i 1) (fxrandom i))))))))

Given this, then
> (let loop ((i 20))
    (display (cond/random (1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
    (newline)
    (if (> i 0) (loop (- i 1)) #f))
2
2
2
6
6
4
4
4
6
2
2
6
2
4
2
6
6
4
2
6
6
#f

